# std::bad_variant_access error when trying to store value to std::variant in map

Tags: c++, c++17, stdmap, std-variant

I'm parsing a file into a map with std::variant (to support two types of values) and I can't figure out the right way to store the value into the map.

I'm getting an:
std::bad_variant_access

what(): unexpected index

This is the map definition:

```
typedef struct op{
   std::string name;
   map<std::string, std::variant<uint16_t,float> > params;
}operation;
```

This is the parsing function:

```
int test(std::string file_name)
{
   ifstream inFile;

   inFile.open(file_name);
   if (!inFile) {
      std::cout << "Unable to open file: " << input_file_name << endl;
      return(-1); 
   }      

   std::string key;
   std::string value;
   operation op;

   /* read op. name. */
   getline(inFile, key, ':') && getline(inFile, value);
   assert(key.compare("op_name") == 0);
   op.name = remove_leading_spaces(value);
 
   getline(inFile, value);
   stringstream s_(value);
   std::string key_;
   while(getline(s_, key_, ':') && getline(s_, value, ',')){ 
        key = remove_leading_spaces(key_);
        if (key.compare("factor") == 0){
            std::get<float>(op.params[key]) = std::stof(value);
        }
        else{
            std::get<uint16_t>(op.params[key]) = std::stoi(value);
        }
   }
.
.
.
// rest of the function is irrelevant 
.
.
```

There is no problem with the uint16_t parsing.

I tried to change the order of the variant so it will be std::variant<float,uint16_t> and then is fails in the else.
So I understand that the way that I'm accessing the variant is wrong (or maybe it's because the map is not initialized?) but I don't know how to fix it.

Should I use std::visit instead of std::get?  if so, how?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`std::variant::emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/emplace). In you code:

```cpp
if (key.compare("factor") == 0){
  op.params[key].emplace<float>(std::stof(value));
} else {
  op.params[key].emplace<uint16>(std::stoi(value));
}
```

But I don't know what `uint16` is – are you actually using `uint16_t`?